# What tag should we use for "what's the difference between X and Y" questions?

Tags: discussion

Since there's so many varieties of beer, there's already a lot of questions on our site about the difference between them. What tag should we use? I considered creation a tag called [characteristics](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characteristics) on [my question related to this](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/28/whats-are-the-differences-between-an-ipa-and-its-variants) but it seemed odd.

What tag should we use? *Should* we use a tag at all or will tagging them by the variants names be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like `styles` or `beer-styles`, but the nerd in me wants `taxonomy`.

Comment: I vote for just `styles`. This is a beer site, so the prefix shouldn't be necessary. Otherwise you end up with `beer-flavour`, `beer-colour`, `beer-ingredients` etc.

Answer (score 2):

[beer-styles](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer-styles) might be a helpful tag to have. Or just [style](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style)/s, along with the appropriate tags for any styles mentioned in the question. (i.e. [stout](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stout))